# Show tht $f(x)$ is either irreducible or it splits in $F$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

> Let $F$ be a field of characteristic $p$ and let $f(x)=x^p-a\in F[x].$
>   Show that $f(x)$ is either irreducible or it splits in $F$.

**Attempt**:

If $b=a^{\frac{1}{p}}\in F$ then $x^p-a=x^p-(a^{\frac{1}{p}})^p=(x-b)^p$.
Thus $f$ splits in $F$.

Now if $b\notin F$, I need to show that $f$ is irreducible. I am unable to understand how to do that .

Will someone please help me to complete this?

Comment: If $(x-b)^r\in F[x]$ then $-rbx^{r-1}\in F[x]$. If $r<p$ you can divide by it and get $b\in F$.

Answer (score 1):

In general $b$ lies in some extension $K/F$. Also $b^p\in F$.
If $(X^p-a)=(X-b)^p$ is reducible over $F$ then each irreducible factor over $K$ has the form $(X-b)^r$ where $1\le r<p$. The $X^{r-1}$ coefficient of this
is $-rb$ which must be in $F$....

Comment: Yes I understand that $X^p-a=(X-b)^p$ in some extension field of $F$.

Comment: But I dont understand how to  show that $f$ splits in $F$?Will you please give some more steps